# Angular 7 upgrade from Angular 6 types error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6, angular7

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/autocomplete/typings/autocomplete-trigger.d.ts(28,77): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ScrollStrategy' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/autocomplete/typings/autocomplete-trigger.d.ts(30,75): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Overlay' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/autocomplete/typings/autocomplete-trigger.d.ts(30,91): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ScrollStrategy' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/autocomplete/typings/autocomplete-trigger.d.ts(33,35): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ScrollStrategy' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/autocomplete/typings/autocomplete-trigger.d.ts(106,67): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Overlay' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/autocomplete/typings/autocomplete-trigger.d.ts(106,194): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Directionality' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/autocomplete/typings/autocomplete-trigger.d.ts(106,269): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ViewportRuler' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/autocomplete/typings/autocomplete.d.ts(40,18): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ActiveDescendantKeyManager' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/badge/typings/badge.d.ts(52,104): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'AriaDescriber' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/bottom-sheet/typings/bottom-sheet-config.d.ts(21,17): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Direction' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/bottom-sheet/typings/bottom-sheet-container.d.ts(26,20): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'CdkPortalOutlet' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/bottom-sheet/typings/bottom-sheet-container.d.ts(39,113): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'FocusTrapFactory' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/bottom-sheet/typings/bottom-sheet-container.d.ts(39,151): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'BreakpointObserver' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/bottom-sheet/typings/bottom-sheet-container.d.ts(43,38): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ComponentPortal' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/bottom-sheet/typings/bottom-sheet-container.d.ts(45,37): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'TemplatePortal' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/bottom-sheet/typings/bottom-sheet-ref.d.ts(32,74): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'OverlayRef' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/bottom-sheet/typings/bottom-sheet.d.ts(28,27): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Overlay' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/bottom-sheet/typings/bottom-sheet.d.ts(29,42): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ComponentType' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/button-toggle/typings/button-toggle.d.ts(174,144): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'FocusMonitor' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/button/typings/button.d.ts(35,16): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Platform' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/button/typings/button.d.ts(35,41): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'FocusMonitor' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/button/typings/button.d.ts(50,27): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Platform' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/button/typings/button.d.ts(50,51): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'FocusMonitor' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/checkbox/typings/checkbox.d.ts(99,108): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'FocusMonitor' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip-list.d.ts(86,18): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'FocusKeyManager' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip-list.d.ts(91,22): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'SelectionModel' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip-list.d.ts(176,100): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Directionality' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip.d.ts(55,67): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'FocusableOption' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/chips/typings/chip.d.ts(113,69): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Platform' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/datetime/native-date-adapter.d.ts(26,50): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Platform' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/ripple/ripple-renderer.d.ts(77,104): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Platform' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/ripple/ripple.d.ts(74,81): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Platform' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/calendar.d.ts(58,22): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ComponentType' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/calendar.d.ts(60,28): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Portal' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/datepicker.d.ts(19,75): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ScrollStrategy' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/datepicker.d.ts(21,73): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Overlay' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/datepicker.d.ts(21,89): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ScrollStrategy' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/datepicker.d.ts(24,35): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ScrollStrategy' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/datepicker.d.ts(62,30): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ComponentType' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/datepicker.d.ts(112,16): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'OverlayRef' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/datepicker.d.ts(129,47): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Overlay' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/datepicker.d.ts(129,167): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Directionality' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/month-view.d.ts(65,123): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Directionality' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/multi-year-view.d.ts(50,93): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Directionality' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/typings/year-view.d.ts(54,123): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Directionality' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-config.d.ts(64,17): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Direction' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-config.d.ts(77,22): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ScrollStrategy' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-container.d.ts(32,20): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'CdkPortalOutlet' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-container.d.ts(45,61): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'FocusTrapFactory' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-container.d.ts(52,38): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ComponentPortal' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-container.d.ts(57,37): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'TemplatePortal' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog-ref.d.ts(32,30): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'OverlayRef' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog.d.ts(20,71): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ScrollStrategy' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog.d.ts(22,69): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Overlay' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog.d.ts(22,85): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ScrollStrategy' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog.d.ts(24,78): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Overlay' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog.d.ts(24,94): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ScrollStrategy' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog.d.ts(27,35): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ScrollStrategy' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog.d.ts(62,27): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Overlay' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog.d.ts(62,178): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'OverlayContainer' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/dialog/typings/dialog.d.ts(70,55): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'ComponentType' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/accordion-base.d.ts(16,43): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'CdkAccordion' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/expansion-panel-header.d.ts(16,68): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'FocusableOption' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/expansion-panel-header.d.ts(22,80): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'FocusMonitor' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/expansion-panel-header.d.ts(49,20): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'FocusOrigin' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/expansion-panel.d.ts(61,14): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'TemplatePortal' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/expansion/typings/expansion-panel.d.ts(66,113): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'UniqueSelectionDispatcher' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/typings/form-field.d.ts(110,115): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Directionality' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/typings/form-field.d.ts(110,182): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Platform' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/grid-list/typings/grid-list.d.ts(32,58): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Directionality' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/input/typings/input.d.ts(30,26): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Platform' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/input/typings/input.d.ts(100,113): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Platform' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/input/typings/input.d.ts(102,175): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'AutofillMonitor' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/selection-list.d.ts(41,116): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'FocusableOption' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/selection-list.d.ts(97,85): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'FocusableOption' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/selection-list.d.ts(100,18): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'FocusKeyManager' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/list/typings/selection-list.d.ts(117,22): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'SelectionModel' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-directive.d.ts(61,16): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Direction' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-directive.d.ts(123,29): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'FocusOrigin' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-item.d.ts(21,75): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'FocusableOption' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-item.d.ts(34,87): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'FocusMonitor' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-item.d.ts(36,20): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'FocusOrigin' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-panel.d.ts(29,17): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Direction' as a type.
node_modules/@angular/material/menu/typings/menu-panel.d.ts(30,31):
```

I tried everything to get this working. I tried versions from 6 all the way to latest, different recommended combinations of Angular/Typescript versions. But I can't find the reason why. I didn't put whole STDOUT of the error here, all the errors are same.

My package.json is set as following:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "7.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.7",
    "@angular/material": "7.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-server": "7.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.7",
    "angular-moment-timezone": "1.7.1",
    "core-js": "2.6.5",
    "http-server": "0.11.1",
    "ie-shim": "0.1.0",
    "ng2-date-picker": "2.11.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "2.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "0.13.4",
    "@angular/cli": "7.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.2.7",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "1.1.8",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "7.3.4",
    "@types/hammerjs": "2.0.36",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.3.9",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.6",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.121",
    "@types/node": "11.9.6",
    "@types/source-map": "0.5.7",
    "@types/uglify-js": "3.0.4",
    "@types/webpack": "4.4.25",
    "@types/angular-material": "1.1.66",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "3.1.3",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "3.9.10",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "5.2.1",
    "codelyzer": "4.5.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "5.0.0",
    "cross-env": "5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "2.1.0",
    "exports-loader": "0.7.0",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.5",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "find-root": "1.1.0",
    "gh-pages": "2.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "imports-loader": "0.8.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "3.3.0",
    "karma": "4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "2.2.5",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "0.1.5",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "3.0.5",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.5.0",
    "node-sass": "4.11.0",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "optimize-js-plugin": "0.0.4",
    "parse5": "5.1.0",
    "protractor": "5.4.2",
    "raw-loader": "1.0.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.3",
    "rxjs-tslint": "0.1.7",
    "sass-loader": "7.1.0",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "2.1.3",
    "source-map-loader": "0.2.4",
    "string-replace-loader": "2.1.1",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "ts-node": "8.0.2",
    "tslib": "1.9.3",
    "tslint": "5.13.1",
    "tslint-loader": "3.5.4",
    "typedoc": "0.14.2",
    "typescript": "3.2.4",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "url-loader": "1.1.2",
    "webpack": "4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "3.2.3",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.2.1",
    "webpack-inline-manifest-plugin": "4.0.1",
    "webpack-merge": "4.2.1",
    "handlebars": "4.1.0"
}
```

I am using starter: https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack-starter

And trying to increase version of angular from 6 to 7. Thanks

Comment: have you followed official upgrade guide https://update.angular.io/

Comment: Done all that. Still getting error.

Comment: Have you tried to downgrade `@angular/material ` to 7.2.0?

Comment: Tried changing the version number, removed lock file, removed all the node_modules, ran npm install and tried to run: npm run server:<env> and got same error once again.

Answer (score 0):

You should also upgrade your `@angular/material` package.

`ng update @angular/material`

Comment: remove the package-lock.json, and try npm install again.

Comment: I removed node_mondules, removed package-lock.json and ran npm install again. Still same result when I tried to run npm run server:<env>.

Comment: what's your global angular cli version and typescript version.

Comment: Don't know about global, but latest for this project as set in package.json file: angular cli 7.3.4 and typescript 3.2.4

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the angular material and angular cdk to resolve your issue

**Update material library**

```
npm update @angular/material
```

**Update CDK(Component Devlopment Kit)**

```
npm update @angular/cdk
```

Here is **[official upgrade guide](https://update.angular.io/)**

Hope this help!